# find line that contains string & echo the value to a new line using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

i want to find the solution in bash script:
i have the raw output logs. Each line begins with a date, e.g. Apr 10 11:17:35

I want to Loop through each log item, and find the lines that contain the string coderbyte heroku/router. For each of those, echo the request_id value to a new line, and if the fwd key has the value of MASKED, then add a [M] to the end of the line with a space before it

output log

```
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=69dff0hba0nv HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad2Es2" host=coderbyte.com request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.2: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad2Es2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=4eiramcmayu0" host=coderbyte.com request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:36 coderbyte app/web.4: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=4eiramcmayu0 HTTP/1.1" 200 3023 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:36 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca fwd="MASKED" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:36 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a fwd="MASKED" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=37ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https
```

here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/logs/web-logs-raw -O > /dev/null
#cat web-logs-raw

grep -F "coderbyte heroku/router" web-logs-raw >> test
cat test
```

This so far can filter the logs and find the lines that contain the string coderbyte heroku/router. but how do i echo the request_id value to a new line, and if the fwd key has the value of MASKED, then add a [M] to the end of the line with a space before it.

Output should be like this

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-000-00000
b19a87a1-1bbb-000-11111
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-22222 [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-33333 [M]
```

Comment: The values of the example output like `b19a87a1-1bbb-000-00000` are not in the output log, but a part of it `b19a87a1-1bbb-` is. Should it be the exact same value?

Comment: sorry it was typo error. It should be "b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa", "910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65", "097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2"

Comment: What's the point of a line that retrieves something and writes it to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
 awk '/coderbyte heroku\/router/ { split($10,map,"=");id=map[2];split($11,map1,"\"");print map1[2]=="MASKED"?id" [M]":id }' web-logs-raw
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/coderbyte heroku\/router/ { # Search for lines with required text
          split($10,map,"="); # Split the 10th space delimited field into the array map using "=" as the field separator
          id=map[2]; # Set the variable id to the the second index of the map array
          split($11,map1,"\""); # Split the 11th field into the array map1 using " as the field separator (this is the masked variable)
          print map1[2]=="MASKED"?id" [M]":id # If the masked entry is MASKED, print "[M]" and then the id otherwise just print the id
     }' web-logs-raw
```

Output:

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```

Comment: Great. If you could then up vote and accept the answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a pattern and to match `coderbyte heroku\/router` and capture the request_id and `fwd="MASKED"` in a capture group.

Test if group 2 is not empty. If it is not, write the request_id followed by  `[M]`, else only write the request id.

Using `gnu-awk` with a third parameter for capturing groups (As mentioned by @[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava))

```
awk '
match($0, /^.*?\<coderbyte heroku\/router\>.* request_id=(\S+) (fwd="MASKED)?/, m) {
  print m[2]? m[1] " [M]": m[1]
}
' web-logs-raw
```

Output

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```

Comment: Just mention that it requires `gnu-awk`

Comment: @anubhava Ok I will, I am new to this. Leaning something new

Comment: `match` function in POSIX awk doesn't have third parameter for capture groups unlike `gnu-awk`

Answer (score 1):

Another option that might be easy and much readable

```
cat web-logs-raw | grep "coderbyte heroku/router" | cut -d' ' -f10,11 | awk -F'=' '{print $2,$3} ' |
 awk -F\" '{print $1,$2}' | cut -d' ' -f1,4 | awk '{ if ( $2 == "MASKED") print $1" [M]"; else print $1 }'
```

Explanation:

```
cat web-logs-raw  | grep "coderbyte heroku/router" | cut -d' ' -f10,11
till this we find this word coderbyte heroku/router and print only request id and fwd fields

Output: 
request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd="108.31.000.000"
request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 fwd="108.31.000.000"
request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 fwd="108.31.000.000"
request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 fwd="108.31.000.000"
request_id=8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca fwd="MASKED"
request_id=10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a fwd="MASKED"

then after this we need to remove requst_id field and fwd`s double questes
cat web-logs-raw | grep "coderbyte heroku/router" | cut -d' ' -f10,11 | awk -F'=' '{print $2,$3} ' |
 awk -F\" '{print $1,$2}'

output:
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd  108.31.000.000
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 fwd  108.31.000.000
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 fwd  108.31.000.000
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 fwd  108.31.000.000
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca fwd  MASKED
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a fwd  MASKED

just after this now we only need to remove the fwd 
cat web-logs-raw | grep "coderbyte heroku/router" | cut -d' ' -f10,11 | awk -F'=' '{print $2,$3} ' |
 awk -F\" '{print $1,$2}' | cut -d' ' -f1,4 

output: 
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa 108.31.000.000
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 108.31.000.000
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 108.31.000.000
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 108.31.000.000
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca MASKED
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a MASKED

then we need to remove this fwd_key field 
cat web-logs-raw | grep "coderbyte heroku/router" | cut -d' ' -f10,11 | awk -F'=' '{print $2,$3} ' |
 awk -F\" '{print $1,$2}' | cut -d' ' -f1,4 | awk '{ if ( $2 == "MASKED") print $1" [M]"; else print $1 }'

output:
19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl

```
$ perl -ne ' $m=/fwd="MASKED"/ ? "[M]":""; /coderbyte heroku\/router/ and /request_id=(\S+)/ and print "$1 $m\n" ' output.log
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/coderbyte heroku\/router/{gsub(/request_id=/,"",$10); print $10, ($11=="fwd=\"MASKED\"" ? "[M]" : "")}' web-logs-raw 

b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa 
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]

$ awk -F'[ ="]' '/coderbyte heroku\/router/{print $18, ($21=="MASKED" ? "[M]" : "")}' web-logs-raw
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa 
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat web-logs-raw | grep -F "coderbyte heroku/router" | awk '{ print $10 " " $11 }' | xargs -d "=" | awk '{ print $2 " " $4}' | sed 's/"/ /g' | while read a b c; do if [[ "$b" == "MASKED" ]]; then echo $a [M]; else echo $a;fi;done

b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mawk '(NF *= / coderbyte heroku\/router:/) && 

($--NF = /MASKED/ ? " [M]" : _)^_' FS='^.+request_id=| [^"]+"|" .+$' OFS=
```

---

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca [M]
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a [M]
```